# Generic Functions for Various Data Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic functions for adding, removing, and editing values stored in a state object. These functions will take a list of objects that extend a base class. The idea is not to write a specific version of the function for each collection. And although this works, the problem is I'm trying to do this where TS does not warn about potential issues.

I tried several things including keyof type, typeof, etc.

```
interface IFee {
  id?: string;
  amount: number;
  description?: string;
}

interface IProduct {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  price: number;
}

interface Client {
  fees: IFee[];
  products: IProduct[];
}

class ClientState {
  private state: Client = {
    fees: [],
    products: [],
  }

  addItem<T>(collection: keyof Client, data: T): T[] {
    const newData: T[] = [
      ...this.state[collection], // < Warning from TS
      data
    ];
    this.state[collection] = newData; // < Warning from TS
    return newData;
  }

  removeItem<T>(collection: keyof Client, id: string): T[] {
    this.state[collection] = this.state[collection]?.filter((i: T) => i.id !== id); // < Warning from TS
    return this.state[collection]; // < Warning from TS
  }
}

const state = new ClientState();
const allFees: IFee[] = state.addItem<IFee>('fees', { amount: 10 });
console.log('allFees', allFees);

state.addItem<IProduct>('products', { id: '1', name: 'Sample Prod 1', price: 10 });
state.addItem<IProduct>('products', { id: '2', name: 'Sample Prod 2', price: 10 });
state.addItem<IProduct>('products', { id: '3', name: 'Sample Prod 3', price: 10 });
const allProducts: IProduct[] = state.addItem<IProduct>('products', { id: '4', name: 'Sample Prod 4', price: 10 });
console.log('allProducts', allProducts);

state.removeItem<IProduct>('products', '2');
const remainingProd = state.removeItem<IProduct>('products', '3');
console.log('remainingProd', remainingProd);
```

Edit: Removed fluff from sample code.
Edit: Removed unrelated code.

Comment: Would you consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleoQm) to be a reasonable [mre]? I don't think the `IBaseEntity` part is your concern, right?

Comment: Your `editItem()` implementation is concerning me.  If you don't find a value with the relevant `id`, then you would be putting a `Partial<T>` into a collection of type `T[]`, which is not good. And if you *do* find a value, then you are going to add the updated version to the end of the array without removing the existing one. Could you remove `editItem()` from your code so that people answering your question don't have to fix it? Or could you fix it?

Comment: In any case, I think the underlying issue here is one of *correlated unions* as discussed in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  The recommended fix for this, as per [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to refactor to a particular generic form where the compiler can follow the correlation. You really have to curate the types in a specific way.  For my version of your example code it looks like [this](//tsplay.dev/wRleYm). Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes removing IBaseEntity would be OK. The idea there would be that the expected collection would be of object that extend that type. However, as you indicated, it's not necessary. The editItem (and in fact the entire thing) is not the final implementation - sorry for the confusion. Your implementation is what I was looking for. There are roughly 20 collection types (and maybe more to in the future) and the sample you provided will work with each of them. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer, but could you please [edit] the code in your question to only demonstrate the issue you're having and not unrelated issues (especially the `editItem()` implementation that duplicates things instead of editing them...  I don't want to spend time in the answer explaining what's going on inside `editItem()`)?

Comment: Sure thing. I removed the code as per your suggestion. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give the compiler enough information that the `collection` key name and the `data` type are appropriate for each other.  In your version, the `collection` could easily be `"products"` but `data` is `IFee` and you're claiming to return an `IFee[]`, but the actual collection returned would be `IProduct[]` (possibly with an `IFee` added in there ).  The compiler is right to be unhappy.

In a perfect world you could change the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature a bit:

```
addItem<K extends keyof Client>(collection: K, data: Client[K][number]): Client[K] { 
  /* impl */ 
}
```

That's saying the type of `data` should be the same as if you [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a `Client` object with a key of type `K` (the same as `collection`) and then index into that with a `number` key.  Since `Client[K]` is an array type, then `Client[K][number]` is the element type for that array.

This certainly helps callers; you don't need to manually specify the data type anymore:

```
const allFees: IFee[] = state.addItem('fees', { amount: 10 }); // okay
```

And you'll get warned if you try to pass the wrong data:

```
state.addItem('products', { id: 'oops', amount: 100 }); // error!
// Argument of type '{ id: string; amount: number; }' is not 
// assignable to parameter of type 'IProduct'.
```

But there are still compiler errors in the implementation:

```
addItem<K extends keyof Client>(collection: K, data: Client[K][number]): Client[K] {
  const newData = [...this.state[collection], data];
  this.state[collection] = newData; // error 
  return newData; // error 
}
```

---

The problem here is that the compiler cannot "see" the correlation between the `this.state[collection]` type and the `data` type for arbitrary `K`.  It's too complicated of a relationship.  This general situation is the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), where it's described as dealing with *correlated unions*; `collection` is  constrained to [the union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `"fees" | "products"` and `data` is constrained to the union `IFee | IProduct`, but these are not independent of each other, and the compiler is often unaware of this dependence.

The recommended fix to this, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to refactor the types to use a simpler mapping type and then express things in terms of this mapping type.  You can read that issue for details.

In the case of this example code it looks like:

```
type ClientData = {
  fees: IFee,
  products: IProduct
}

type Client<K extends keyof ClientData = keyof ClientData> = {
  [P in K]: ClientData[P][] 
}
```

So `ClientData` is the simpler mapping type, and `Client` is a *distributive object type* that maps the data from `ClientData` to arrays.  `Client` by itself is equivalent to your prior version, while `Client<K>` for a particular generic `K` can be used to look at just the key-value mapping for a particular `K`.

Now we can write `addItem()` and `removeItem()` like this:

```
addItem<K extends keyof ClientData>(collection: K, data: ClientData[K]): ClientData[K][] {
  const state: Client<K> = this.state;
  const coll: ClientData[K][] = state[collection];
  const newData = [...coll, data];
  state[collection] = newData;
  return newData;
}

removeItem<K extends keyof ClientData>(collection: K, id: string): ClientData[K][] {
  const state: Client<K> = this.state;
  const coll: ClientData[K][] = state[collection];
  state[collection] = coll.filter((i => i.id !== id));
  return state[collection];
}
```

The call signatures are now written in terms of `ClientData`, but it works just the same from the caller's side.

As for the implementation, the compiler needs help recognizing the assignability of the various values involved:  We copy `this.state`, known to be of type `Client`, to `state` of type `Client<K>`, and this assignment is verified as safe.  We also copy `state[collection]`, known to be of type `Client<K>[K]` to `coll` of type `ClientData[K][]`, and this assignment is also verified as safe.  Armed with these, we can perform array operations on `coll` and still end up with `ClientData[K][]`, and then we can assign this to `state[collection]`, whose type `Client<K>[K]` is seen as equivalent to `ClientData[K][]` as per the definition of `Client`.

If you try to streamline this by assigning to `this.state[collection]` directly, you'll find that it doesn't work.  The compiler gets confused with types like `(Client<keyof ClientData>[K][number])[]` and complains.  The above assignments were specifically curated to help the compiler verify type safety.

---

So there you go.  Honestly I wouldn't expect most developers to figure out how to lead the compiler through this type analysis minefield.  And there are probably modifications to this example where there is no way to do it.  In such cases, you can always fall back to the judicious use of a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  As long as you can convince yourself that `[...this.state[collection], data]` will definitely be of the type `Client[K]` (that is, it's an array of the same type of elements as `data`), then you can just assert it and move on:

```
addItem<K extends keyof Client>(collection: K, data: Client[K][number]): Client[K] {
  const newData = [...this.state[collection], data] as Client[K]; // just assert this
  this.state[collection] = newData;
  return newData; 
}
```

Type assertions are an admission that you know more than the compiler about the type of some expression and a claim that you are taking on the responsibility for the veracity of that assertion, even in the face of possible future changes to the code.  That responsibility shift is why type assertions are best avoided where possible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDEIoN4ChnLAAmA-AFzIDOYUoA5gNz7JwC2A9gK7gUiesAjaEwJEIlBLQAOYYOxDkqNekwC+uXKEixEKVAAUo7IpwRhkeAsUXVaIRsxBsIFWyuZiJ02fJvL7IshStEi8-EJQahpgAJ5SKADCADbAEOAAInBgcMgAvBbMMFiUFBhYADTMwcamYCVohjVmuOq4sfHIyangADwA0sgQAB6QIESUyADWEDHsMJ0paWCZ2XlTM3ML3ctZcAB8a5bIANr6hCDIfQC6FF1LK3CnV8dXyK0ISXCUE3fgAMrZSAFAjBYAANyyKGokNui3Ah2YBCK4goL0qBBBRhMZnqaOYrQIcCIRFQkFYAOASSSACEif1BiM0uN1rN5r8wHsABQIdhUiBmOQgCh9crIIi7WHbY7XY58QTQK4ASklS2lryOBB5IGoyBAEAA7g81scAHRmsAAC2AlBN0Mgxx5fIF8iuovF2SugQIluttsBEAdvKS-J8IFe+T1ht2DGQAHpY4MoEYoIjkFAIGBOFALpGHjH44nk-iNITiaSIOTZFSKVTaUR6cNRszpqytvddlzHcHnULLm6JW2Mrs1crBztsmqXhYMTPkKmtTrc7tjWaTT6bXaA12Q4LXWLdp7U+u-ZDA07Q+HdQa83GE5z2Q81cgAD5jnotzYPjuTuURJUvVN00zbMryjbIY2LZgiRJMkG0ZMYJg-Nk4XHfZuSDHd5GFftshVIcJ2uUcvwI551XneQdU3PCwH6A58mPTcvWQBdzC7ajHxlS9NzPbsLyYljQKNfJTTNLscLgQ8Z247ce0vJdwMAjMsxza9o0gqCyzJABxdhjAAURALg6AtOCm0QjZkO2TsMJ7bD91wscf3CBUiJQp8NWYijzHknJhNXBj-R4zCw3E14vkc658wTAArTgdS+ShoHMdcjytDdApki81h8pigOUwToznAgCTTCt2DBCBy1YUymXM1tiLQzLBTs4hXH8OhXO2DjSOBDEBKot8+jo5AAshfivM8ql2OHTi1mkmy+NTebz13NYuxNGBKW0TlOWAPIDmAE1iGQABCXJ8mIRVFVypSQOW3jd0CVp3gmzdsoNMcAUhTlro0TcTWgqrOQAcmqbE6mB0VsEIIgKGB3SpEoSGWA4bgwAoABGAAGLG3mu29C3YKATtwAsAEEoDofglmQTZ2hQYHodapQ7EYFGuB4XVnMiN5gcICZDPMUmEwS4A6CcARgxG9ggjgKBnG0Wn5np5BgYMLFamBk0-v9E10w4CqgdBjWcWR+H2ER4HftwAS4CpTAUTQB2p3yf7AbJEHkSRqH2bRzHcdUfGC3YSY4BiG2KN5CATSSdg6BBu2kgd72WHt4prbdzSKxBsHahTpnYdVjHkacVgXFVv42CkKXGiIZBi9FUFQnrgPfszmDs+NpoIZ95ngYAJhL5w4cr1hq5QWvkEHxuQnL7G8aYdujdz03e8L4GAGYh7Lkeq5rrFkC3mfgGb+fA6YW2qVrvPSmvswXaUSEAaz1gc5Nnvpz7gAWbfy+B0fx7IEnj-Y+p9W4X0jsGGOccE5X3finROd86gZ11vrcqlUPZd3BinAeVsIHanMPrOAoB6CT1dqgsqhtMErw-pvPBEdtRR2gfHYGRCSH2FrsjNhIBSFYl+kAA)

Comment: This is a perfect answer. It works great. Thank you very much for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Fantastic answer! (as always :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is just my 2 cents, in the hope that someone like @jcalz can improve on it.

TypeScript unfortunately struggles with generics in cases like this, where you are using a key of an object to determine types, as it results in unions and intersections that don't actually represent what constraints are on the values.

You could try this:

```
class ClientState {
  private state: Client = {
    fees: [],
    products: [],
  };

  addItem<CollectionKey extends keyof Client>(
    collection: CollectionKey,
    data: Client[CollectionKey][number]
  ): Client[CollectionKey] {
    (this.state[collection] as Client[CollectionKey][number][]).push(data);
    return this.state[collection];
  }

  removeItem<CollectionKey extends keyof Client>(
    collection: CollectionKey,
    id: string
  ): Client[CollectionKey] {
    (this.state[collection] as Client[CollectionKey][number][]) = (
      this.state[collection] as Client[CollectionKey][number][]
    ).filter((i) => i.id !== id);
    /* Or:
    const index = this.state[collection].findIndex(
      (i: Client[CollectionKey][number]) => i.id !== id
    );
    this.state[collection].splice(index, 1);
    */
    return this.state[collection];
  }
}
```

This uses the collection *key* as the generic, allowing the types to inferred at usage from the collection key.
It unfortunately requires some casting hacks to get it to work. Alternatives are `@ts-ignore` comments or different methods.
Note that the behavior of the arrays is modified slightly, as the internal array is returned, not a copy created in `addItem`.

Then, the functions can be called like this:

```
state.addItem("products", {
  id: "1",
  name: "Sample Prod 1",
  price: 10,
});

state.removeItem("products", "2");
```